# Validating range where minimum=maximum on jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Currently my jQuery slider prevents the user from progressing if the range is 0-0 and 1000-1000. How do I make it work across a range of values such as 10-10,20-20,30-30...990-990 without having to define each manually.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/46/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xSkgH/53/

Basically just check whether your lower and upper values are the same

```
    if (lower == upper) {
        alert("Please select two different values");
    } else {
        $("#errorMessage").html("");
    }
```